# Reg exp to accept only one comma in the number in oninput event in angular typescript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

I am trying to have textbox aceepts only numbers having only one dot or comma in the input value. below code works fine takes 1 dot

```
 <input type="text" id="Id" name="Name" 
        oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
       >
```

but i also need to support one comma based on locale.
can anyone please correct my reg exp which accepts one comma or if dot is taken comma shouldnt accept vice versa.
thanks in advance

Comment: i need it in oninput. like how i have written above. i got many reg exp but unable to match with replace

Comment: @5584196 The closest what you can reach with regexp is to filter down to one `.` and `,` in the message. If you want more, create your own function where you iterate through and checking the characters. Or you use a solution like @ManirajMurugan suggested and you provide an error message if the user didn't manage the correct format. Also from regex you can't determinate which is the correct sign. What you may can do the query down the correct sign for the current user's local and dynamically inject into the regex expression.

Comment: @golddragon007 : i can get navigator.language and replace . with , but i wanted input to affect immediately rather doing much code as u said. i already have that thought what u explained.